# Android SearchView Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I want to disable the Mag icon displayed inside the search view component. Any idea how to reference it and remove it or replace it with another drawable ?

[image]

Comment: Wonders why would some one down vote the question ?

Comment: what about white line below SearchView icon - how to customize it?

Comment: @mattblang yeah. please email me i will try to pull the code and share it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Your parent theme">
<item name="android:searchViewSearchIcon">@android:drawable/ic_search</item>
</style>
```

**Edit:**
`searchViewSearchIcon` is a private attribute. This answer therefore does not work (on the native ActionBar).

Comment: Set it to `@android:color/transparent` to remove it, or change it to what you would like.

Comment: is there any list of what u can modify any where ?

Comment: omg. this is awesome. Thanks a lot. I wont have to post anymore question related to Action bar Styling :D

Comment: Hi @Ahmad I am using <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
         <item name="android:searchViewSearchIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>      
    </style> but it give me "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:searchViewSearchIcon'"

Comment: `android:searchViewSearchIcon` is private. This answer does not work at all.

Comment: This only works if using ActionBarSherlock. With native actionbar, searchViewSearchIcon is not public. You'd have compile errors.

Comment: if i set transparent - icon still have space before hint.
how to make it GONE?

Comment: It also works with v7 app compat, but you need to drop the android: from the item name.

Comment: <item name="*android:searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item> works

Comment: I am using actionBarSherlock but this still doesn't work due to private

Answer (score 15):

Since the wording of the question does not contain any mention of `ActionBarSherlock` (except for the tag) and comments have been added that the accepted answer does not work for standard and/or support library action bar, I'm posting another answer. Here is the Java code for `onCreate`:

```
// obtain action bar
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

// find SearchView (im my case it's in a custom layout because of left alignment)
View v = actionBar.getCustomView();
SearchView searchView = (SearchView)v.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
ImageView icon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);

// method 1: does not work persistently, because the next line
// should be probably called after every manipulation with SearchView
// icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

// method 2: working code
icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
icon.setMaxWidth(0);
icon.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
icon.setImageDrawable(null);
```

<sub>According to this [post](http://wtanaka.com/node/8049), while using a `SearchView` from the support library (`android-support-v7-appcompat` in my case) with `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` the icon is displayed outside edit textbox (`SearchAutoComplete`). Otherwise (`setIconifiedByDefault(true)`) it's displayed inside the box. The presented code is used for disabled "iconification" by default, and may require some changes to work with "iconified" search view. I don't know if the same applies to `ActionBarSherlock`.</sub>

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm using appcompat SearchView and i have that icon inside edit textbox and i can't make it gone. do you have some other ideas?

Comment: You should probably check which version your library is and look at its sources, specifically at layout file. For example, if you look at [this Android sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml) you'll see that `search_mag_icon` is outside `search_plate`. With the source you can deduce which elements to "find" in your layout.

Comment: i have the last version of SupportLibrary and in resources search_mag_icon is outside everywhere. may be that icon is not search_mag_icon but some icon inside SearchAutoComplete ? 
How can i find resources for that?

Comment: Well, I updated the library yesterday as well, and the code above worked for me. I suppose there can be something else specific in your project. Can you post some code and detailed explanation on what goes wrong, probably in a separate question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21095523/2281717 - i create new question with code details, please help if you can.
I tried your method to change icon of that search :
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_remove);
- but no result

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. If the searchview is iconifiedbydefault, search_mag_icon is not found, thus I cannot change the search icon. But if I set it to false, the id is found, thus the icon is changed. The problem is that I need the icon to be inside the textfield. Have you figured out a way why it doesn't work for iconified searchview ?

Comment: @Andrew, no, I haven't.

Answer (score 7):

This icon is hint. So you can simply set new hint text.

```
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);

    searchPlate.setHint("Search");
```

If you want icon as hint text use spanable string with ImageSpan

```
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);


    searchPlate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.search_text_color));
    SpannableString string = new SpannableString(" ");
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_search);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    string.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    searchPlate.setHint(string);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this line in your MenuItem `android:iconifiedByDefault="@android:color/transparent"`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/activity_home_action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/activity_home_search_title"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="@android:color/transparent"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

Or you can make programatically `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.activity_home_action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the hint search button:

```
mNearMeSearchBar = (SearchView) mView.findViewById(R.id.nearme_search_component_nearme_edittext);
mNearMeSearchBar.setIconifiedByDefault(false); //Removes Search Hint Icon
```

To change the search button drawable:

```
int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
ImageView v = (ImageView) mNearMeSearchBar.findViewById(searchImgId);
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_compass);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to customize the `SearchView` style like this:

```
<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_arrow_back</item>
</style>
```

And then add it in your `AppTheme`.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--   your other colors and styles -->
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to your search view using the tag `style`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            style="@style/MySearchViewStyle"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false" />
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the v7 app compat library you can easily change this in the theme. In your theme that extends from an AppCompat theme just add a line like:

```
<item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines removed the magnifying glass:

```
    //remove search icon
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
    icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme style include this:

```
<style name="YourTheme.Toolbar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/YourActionBarSearch</item>
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/your_ab_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/your_ab_hint_color</item>
</style>
```

You can now define the style of the SearchView with `searchViewStyle`, and `editTextColor` will set the color of the text in the search box. By setting `android:textColorHint` you will also set the color of the hint, e.g. "Search...".

```
<style name="YourActionBarSearch" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.SearchView">
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_ab_search</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="submitBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="defaultQueryHint">@null</item>
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/ic_ab_small_search_close</item>
</style>
```

This will style your search view as you like, more or less. The field `searchIcon` is the icon in the action bar. **The field `searchHintIcon` is the small icon to the left of the hint in the search field**, which you are asking for in your question; set it to `@null` to remove the icon. The field `closeIcon` is the close icon at the right side of the search field.

Answer (score 0):

In xml in searchView component add next :

```
app:searchHintIcon="@null"
```