# AppCompat SearchView icon can't be GONE

Tags: android, customization, android-support-library, searchview, android-appcompat

[image: SearchView icon]

I'm using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView and i need to make this search icon GONE.
I have custom ActionBar layout with SearchView:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

initialize SearchView :

```
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);

    AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    searchText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, -padding);
    searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));

    View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_plate);
    searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.searchview_textfield);

    View close = searchPlate.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
    close.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectable_background_orange);
```

I was trying to customize searchIcon like this:

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
```

trying to set everything from here [Android SearchView Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21080023/2281717) but it's not that ImageView. 
Can anyone help me plz?

Comment: Off the cuff, that's probably not an `ImageView`, but a compound drawable.

Comment: maybe, but for what?.. i can't make it gone...

Comment: You can log the icon to check if it's an `ImageView` (it is indeed an `ImageView` in my case). Please, specify what's the issue.

Comment: BTW, are you sure you get proper instance of `SearchView`? I have had a similar issue when action bar did actually contain two search views (one was added via custom layout, and the second - in `onCreateOptionsMenu`).

Comment: It looks like I found an answer [here](http://wtanaka.com/node/8049). The `SearchView` layout seems working differently depending from `setIconifiedByDefault`. Mine is `false`, while yours is `true` (I suppose). Please, check if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void setSearchViewEditTextHint(Context context, SearchView searchView, int stringId){
    int searchMagIconId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(searchMagIconId);
    if (null != textView) {
        textView.setHint(stringId);
    }
}
```

Function call:

```
setSearchViewEditTextHint(this, searchView, R.string.emptyString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Sorry I'm a little late to the party. I am having to do a similar thing. I need to change the icon. It's a bit of a hack but I think its the best possible solution. Looking in the support library code AOSP uses "Search_mag_icon" as the icon you are looking for. In your code you can do something like: 
`int searchMagIcon = getResources().getIdentifier("search_mag_icon", "id", "android");
ImageView SearchHintIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchMagIcon);`
and that will save that ImageView. Then you can simply change it or set it to null in your case.

*Edit* There is also a `mSearch.getSearchView().setIconifiedByDefault()` as well as a `mSearch.getSearchView().setIconified()` that you can use. I find that you MUST set the bydefault one to see results.

Hope that helps. :-)