# How to design search view widget?not search bar or app.searchview.

Tags: android, android-widget, searchview

I am using search view widget in my app,so i have tried lot of way to design search view like changing its search icon and search hint etc..only background gets change.

```
   <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <!--        <item name="queryBackground"></item>
            &lt;!&ndash; Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) &ndash;&gt;
            <item name="submitBackground"></item>
            &lt;!&ndash; Close button icon &ndash;&gt;
            <item name="closeIcon"></item>-->
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@drawable/temp_search</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/temp_search</item>
    <!--    &lt;!&ndash; Go/commit button icon &ndash;&gt;
        <item name="goIcon"></item>
        &lt;!&ndash; Voice search button icon &ndash;&gt;
        <item name="voiceIcon"></item>
        &lt;!&ndash; Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row &ndash;&gt;
        <item name="commitIcon"></item>-->
    <!--        <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@drawable/searchbg</item>-->




</style>
```

so how make it customize or design.

Comment: Can you most the xml of the widget? Normally you can change the hint from the widget itself

Comment: But hint and search icon is there even in xml as you said,but it did'nt make any effect when we run to the device,it remains as older.

Comment: Can you tell EXACTLY what changes do you want on the search widget layout design? It will help us understand a bit more.

Comment: I want to change my search icon  mainly,that cant work well now,though i was used styles and add the styles to search view xml as above.but no change...........

Comment: Maybe one cannot change the search mag icon as it is private.Please check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006150/android-searchview-icon